# How to display UIAlertView in centre

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uialertview

I am facing trouble in UIAlertView. In iOS6 its working fine but in iOS7 
some times it appear in centre of screen and some time at left side. 
Any suggestion how to fixed it ? or is it apple bug ? As i am using 
native UIAlertView initWithTitle method.

Here is the code

```
infoAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
      message:message delegate:nil 
      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

[image: UIAlertView in iOS7]

Comment: could you add the code related to this problem

Comment: Here is the code

infoAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

Comment: its resolved. Issue what that i was calling infoAlert 2 to 3 times with out dismissing its previous instance. Now before calling infoAlert , i am checking if its already exist or not. Incase yes i am calling this 
[infoAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; then calling [infoAlert show].